# Enabling CORS to access AWS API Gateway?

Tags: jquery, cors, amazon-gateway

I'm trying to access an AWS API Gateway with jQuery like:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: _config.api.invokeUrl + '/mymodel/' + id + '/attr',
    headers: {
        Authorization: authToken
    },
    data: {},
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(result){
        console.log('success:'+result);
    },
    error: function ajaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error('Error: ', textStatus, ', Details: ', errorThrown);
        console.error('Response: ', jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

However, jQuery/browser reports the CORS error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://sd98fsf98.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/mymodel/123/attr. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

Clearly, I can't fix it by hosting my code from `sd98fsf98.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. I can't find any option in the Gateway API settings to disable this check. How do I bypass the CORS restriction?

Comment: You don't want to disable the check (which is in the client), you want to enable CORS hearders on your Gateway API config. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable CORS in your API gateway.
This sets us an options method which adds the required headers for cross-origin access.

**In your API Gateway console:
Actions -> Enable Cors[Select '*' for everyone] -> Deploy API**
[image: CORS]

After deploying the API, the requests will first get the headers from the options method and then redirect to the GET method and will succeed.

[image: DEPLOY]

Please find more information on enabling CORS in the AWS DOCS:
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ashwani Jha answer and peeebeee comment see this article: 
https://enable-cors.org/server_awsapigateway.html

> Amazon API Gateway adds support for CORS enabling through a simple
>   button in the API Gateway console. Unfortunately that button has a
>   partial behavior, thus setting CORS correctly only for 200 answer (so
>   not other HTTP status codes) and ignoring JQuery header support. The
>   best solution considered so far is about avoiding to use the CORS
>   button and set configurations manually. This can be achieved in a
>   couple of steps:
>
> 1. Log into API Gateway console
> 2. Create all the REST resources that
>      needs to be exposed with their methods before setting up CORS (if
>      new resources/methods are created after enabling CORS, these steps
>      must be repeated)
> 3. Select a resource
> 4. Add OPTIONS method, choose as
>      integration type "mock"
> 5. For each Method of a resource
> 6. Go to Response Method
> 7. Add all the response method that should be supported (i.e.
>      200, 500, etc.)
> 8. For each response code set Response Headers to
>
>    - X-Requested-With
>    - Access-Control-Allow-Headers
>    - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
>    - Access-Control-Allow-Methods
> 9. Go to Integration Response, select one of the created response codes, then
>      Header Mappings
> 10. Insert default values for headers example:
>
>     - X-Requested-With: '*'
>     - Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,x-requested-with'
>     - Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'
>     - Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
>         'POST,GET,OPTIONS'
>
> This operation has to be repeated for each method, including the newly
>   created OPTIONS
>
> 11. Deploy the API to a stage
> 12. Check using http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client that CORS requests have been successfully enabled